# can i remove all data set by the previous install of app Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to delete any existing data set by a previous install of same app (databse tables and shared preferences etc) when the app is re-installed?

I have an app that stores some values in sqlite database, if the app is re-installed without prior properly uninstalling. I face problems from previous database entries etc.

Comment: It must delete all data when the app is re-installed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If uninstalling the app didn't do the stuff try this :

```
System Parameters -> Manage Applications -> Your Application -> Clear data
```

If you click on the button (Clear data) you will see a dialog which shows you what kind of data will be cleared.

**Edit**:
If you want to do that programmatically, you can :

1. Change database version in the `super` method of the constructor:

   `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, NEW_DB_VERSION);`
2. Add a `drop` statement before creating tables.

   `database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table");
   database.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE your_table ...");`
3. Proceed to a hard drop of the database:

   `this.context.deleteDatabase(YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;`

Comment: I know user can do it this way, can i programatically in the app code drop all table etc when the app runs for the first time or is isntalled?

Answer (score 1):

Its very Simple.

First Delete the table using `drop` query

```
sdb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename");
```

and then again use the `create table` query

```
sdb.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE tablename(col1 TEXT PRIMARY KEY)");
```

or

delete the DB file using file explorer in path  `data->data->package->databases->dbname`

Comment: should i drop table before creating the table?

Comment: yes.you have to drop table before creating the table.but be careful,it should be called only once, otherwise you cant save any data

Comment: what i am trying to say is make sure that drop command is called beacuse,if that drop command is called after storing the datas it will delete saved data

Answer (score 0):

update the **Database version** to greater value in the **OpenHelper**, it will automatically drop all the tables in database and recreate them.

For shared preferences.. you can clear them from the **OpenHelper** when `onUpgrade` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ankit Popli said, Using version is the right way to go:

```
  public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION   = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME    = "YourDBName.db";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      // ALl the deletion operation here.
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Database.TABLE);       
      onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

AndroidSqlite will automatically call onUpgrade function when the version number is incremented. Do all the database deletion there.